# View animated using CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout getting crazy (sometimes)

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This thing is getting me nuts.

I have been able to get this behavior (exactly what I want): [http://i.imgur.com/PGhL22k.gif](https://i.imgur.com/PGhL22k.gif)

And this is the behavior is has when I scroll down very fast: [http://i.imgur.com/kk7icAc.gif](https://i.imgur.com/kk7icAc.gif) and [http://i.imgur.com/YNPNiA6.gif](https://i.imgur.com/YNPNiA6.gif)

I am sorry but the GIFs are larger than 2Mb and I cannot upload them here...

I want the pagination bar at the bottom to hide the same amount the toolbar does. When scrolling slowly it goes very well, but when fast scrolling it has a really strange behavior as you can see at the GIFs provided above.

This is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:kiosk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            layout="@layout/android_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            kiosk:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        kiosk:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/paginator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        kiosk:layout_behavior="carl.fri.fer.views.KioskPaginator.KioskPaginatorScrollBehaviour"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The "android_toolbar" include is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carl.fri.fer.views.KioskToolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

And the "paginator_layout" is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carl.fri.fer.views.KioskPaginator.KioskPaginator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/kpPaginator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCurrentPage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_pure_black"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMoreOptions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotalPages"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_pure_black"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
</carl.fri.fer.views.KioskPaginator.KioskPaginator>
```

And the ScrollBehavior is as follows:

```
public class KioskPaginatorScrollBehaviour extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

    public KioskPaginatorScrollBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        float depY = - dependency.getHeight();
        depY -= dependency.getY();

        Utils.log("dependency", "" + depY);

        child.setTranslationY(depY);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Inside of every page of the **ViewPager**, there is a Fragment. And the content of this Fragment is a **RecyclerView** with dynamic content. All the content from the **RecyclerView** is loaded from database and images are loaded at runtime.

Can someone please tell me why is this strange behavior happening? How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance...

**EDIT 1:**

I just spotted the cause of the weird behavior! The ViewPager loads the current page and the adjoining ones. The content of the RecyclerView loads from the Internet and as soon as it is loaded, it goes into the RecyclerView. The ViewPager first loads the current page and then the adjoining ones. If I have scrolled down the current page RecyclerView (Toolbar is hidden) when the 2nd RecyclerView just loads and shows the content, it resets the current page AppBarLayout behavior, so it resets my custom view behavior... How can I fix that? I want to avoid not loading adjoining views..

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, it happens when loading adjoining pages of `ViewPager` and **also** when loading from the Internet images inside the `RecyclerView`... this is crazy.

Comment: Can you publish project somewhere (e.g. on github) in order we can easily to reproduce problem?

Comment: I am sorry but this is a private project... I think that there is almost all information you need. However, I will try to abstract it into another project to try to reproduce the problem there.

Comment: Just create project which reproduces issue. No need to publish your real project.

Comment: I will do it tomorrow, now I should be sleeping... Tomorrow I will edit the question with a link to the mock project. Thank you.

Comment: Guess you should post your `KioskToolbar` and `KioskPaginator` classes as well. Cause I've tried to replicate your code fully despite that classes, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I just spotted the cause of the weird behavior! The `ViewPager` loads the current page and the adjoining ones. The content of the `RecyclerView` loads from the Internet and as soon as it is loaded, it goes into the `RecyclerView`. The `ViewPager` first loads the current page and then the adjoining ones. If I have scrolled down the current page `RecyclerView` (Toolbar is hidden) when the 2nd `RecyclerView` just loads and shows the content, it resets the current page `AppBarLayout` behavior, so it resets my custom view behavior... How can I fix that? I want to avoid not loading adjoining views..

Comment: @KrLx_roller, quick and dirty workaround - `viewPager. setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`, which will make not to load any other fragment except the currently visible, thus no collision.

Comment: @azizbekian I would like to avoid doing that because I think it is very useful for my users to keep the `ViewPagers`' behaviour as is...

Comment: Any idea? This is getting me nuts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally resolved your problem - make your custom behavior extending `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` instead of `ScrollingViewBehavior` and it will work as expected. Just set the value to your view's translationY, that is opposite to Y of `AppBarLayout`:

```
public class KioskPaginatorScrollBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    public KioskPaginatorScrollBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        float depY = -dependency.getY();
        child.setTranslationY(depY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are my HERO! I will do some more tests and as soon as I am sure this is the definitive fix, I will reward you with that +200 reputation ;). I will do some research now about the differences between `AppBarLayout.ScrollingBehavior` and `CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour<View>` but in the meantime, do you know it? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Well, `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` is extending `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` itself, and have some logic for nested scrolling. As recommended in guides, you should extend `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` when you want to create your custom behavior :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I should have missed something important when reading how to create custom behavior...